# How to select text on image in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, image, ipad

Hi I am working on e-book application where the pages of the book are displayed as SVG files.as a part of my application functionality i should able to select text from the SVG files which are rendered as images on web view.can anbody suggest me a way to do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you display the SVG? I'd think you do that in WebView. In that case you'd have to provide the text as a separate layer using HTML elements as an "overlay" over the displayed SVG.

I don't think iOS/WebView lets you select text from a SVG through WebView.

Comment: Hi badat,Ya i did rendering of SVG on web View only.can you tell me how to add text as overlay in little detail.

Answer (score 0):

but why do you say the svg is rendered as "image"?

if you load te .svg file in a UIWebView directly or via an HTML file which load the svg...

it should be able to load the "normal" menu with "copy", "select"...

if you need only the "copy" menuItem
just add this:

```
-(void)copy:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"COPY!!");
    [super copy:sender];
}
```

in the UIViewController of your UIWebView.

It works for me for all the html pages and for a .svg files with some text inside it

(i mean that the text to copy is in "myFile.svg")